# Define regex of interceptor of Flume's source to filer logs in a file

Tags: regex, events, interceptor, flume

I would like to use interceptor to filter one log file (event file), this log file contains logs of the whole system and I only want to filter log line (event line) having
com.threesixone.analytic.service.ActionLogAspect, and only want to get the json part of the log line,

Can anyone help me with the regex of interceptor, I have difficulties in understanding the pattern to filter.

Below is example of one log line:

```
2015-11-04 11:09:30,383 INFO : com.threesixone.analytic.service.ActionLogAspect - {"page":"PRODUCT_LIST","controller":"ProductController","product":{"productID":10004,"category":"321","sportCategories":["32"],"name":"Men pullover","gender":"Men","sport":"Running","retailPrice":239.0,"sellPrice":239.0,"sellQuantity":0,"taxablePrice":0.0,"origin":"361° Sports","stockQuantity":1000,"subTotal":0.0},"browser":"Chrome-43.0.2357.130","action":"VIEW","timestamp":1446610170382,"customerType":"GUEST","sessionId":"1et7dn6qbbfui1xszk627pz0p9"}
```

Comment: how about `^.*INFO\s*:\s*com\.threesixone\.analytic\.service\.ActionLogAspectcom\.threesixone\.analytic\.service\.ActionLogAspect\s*\-\s*(.*)$` .. captured group 1 contains your json